# YouTube API v3 PHP unable to connect

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm experiencing a weird issue with the YouTube API v3 (with the php library) : When I send a request, it works, but only one time per request. If I ask for my 4 last uploads, it works, then if I ask for my 3 last uploads, it works, but if I ask again for my 4 last uploads, I get this :

```
An client error occurred: HTTP Error: Unable to connect: '0'
```

Here is my code :

```
<?php

require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';

$DEVELOPER_KEY = 'AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4RXo';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);




$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$uploadsListId = 'UUVoQooxxxxxxxxxAv7xag';



try 
{

$youtubeResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
'maxResults' => 1,
'playlistId' => $uploadsListId
  ));



} catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
die('<p>A service error occurred: <code>'.htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()).'</code></p>');
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
die('<p>An client error occurred: <code>'.htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()).'</code></p>');
}

?>
```

It's the first time that I use this API so maybe I'm missing something.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the youtube API library code in [Google_IO_Stream](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/e8318b1d9ad31714c8f2c21c89d8e79d86e473c9/src/Google/IO/Stream.php) and [Google_IO_Abstract](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/70dd093df91738c0261a002935fab4397986ec89/src/Google/IO/Abstract.php), you are getting the `UNKNOWN_ERROR` code, which is `0`.

You can't know what the error is since the `fopen` call is suppressed at the `Google_IO_Stream` class ([line 102](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/e8318b1d9ad31714c8f2c21c89d8e79d86e473c9/src/Google/IO/Stream.php#L102)). I suggest you remove the `@` sign at the `@$fh = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);` line and run your code again to get the error message.

Comment: Ok now I get the same issue but with this above : 
`Warning: fopen(compress.zlib://https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&amp;maxResults=7&amp;playlistId=UUVoQoxxxxxxxsAv7xag&amp;key=AIzaSyCaKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxSZJO4RXo): failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\wamp\www\Mairie\Google\IO\Stream.php on line 102`

I really don't understand it.
Thank you for your interest in my problem!

Comment: Well that's not a helpful message at all. If you use IDE, I suggest you create a breakpoint and do a line-by-line analysis to see why the first request works. Taking a wild guess, maybe you could try disabling gzip.

Comment: I just realised that when I try the request by using the url in my browser, I get the response at every try (the JSON response). That's weird too. But I also realised that in my case, decoding the url response do the trick too. So that's what I'll do. Thank you for your help !